# Create function to find the key of the values in dictionary that matches alphabetical letters found in string (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, dictionary

I want to create a function to find the key of the values contained in a dictionary that matches the alphabetical letters found in a string.
This is my dictionary:

```
dict = {'0': {'a','c','d','e','b','f'},
             '1': {'c','b'},
             '2': {'a','d','e','b','g'},
             '3': {'a','c','d','b','g'},
             '4': {'g','c','f','b'},
             '5': {'a','c','d','g','f'},
             '6': {'a','c','d','e','g','f'},
             '7': {'a','c','b'},
             '8': {'a','c','d','e','b','g','f'},
             '9': {'a','c','d','b','g','f'}}
```

This is the function that I have tried to create thus far:

```
def guess_character(display, state):
    for key, value in display.items():
        if state == "".join(list(value)[:len(state)]):
            return key
        else:
            pass
```

When I test out my function with these print statements:

```
print(guess_character(seven_segment, 'abed'))
print(guess_character(seven_segment, 'a'))
print(guess_character(seven_segment, 'abcdefg'))
```

This is my **current output**:

```
None
None
None
```

However, this is my **desired output**:

```
{'2', '8', '0'}
{'5', '7', '6', '0', '3', '9', '2', '8'}
{'8'}
```

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: There's no **return** statement in your function *guess_character*.

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for pointing that out! I have added it in now but it still prints `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try.

You can use `all` to check if all the characters are present in *value* corresponding to the *key* or not.

```
def guess_character(d,state):
    return {k for k,v in d.items() if all(i in v for i in state)}

my_dict =   {'0': {'a','c','d','e','b','f'},
             '1': {'c','b'},
             '2': {'a','d','e','b','g'},
             '3': {'a','c','d','b','g'},
             '4': {'g','c','f','b'},
             '5': {'a','c','d','g','f'},
             '6': {'a','c','d','e','g','f'},
             '7': {'a','c','b'},
             '8': {'a','c','d','e','b','g','f'},
             '9': {'a','c','d','b','g','f'}}

print(guess_character(my_dict, 'abed'))
# {'0', '2', '8'}
print(guess_character(my_dict, 'a'))
# {'0', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
print(guess_character(my_dict, 'abcdefg'))
# {'8'}
```

Comment: This works Chester! Thank you! But is there any way to preserve the order of the keys as show in the desired output?

Comment: What order @jackie? Can elaborate on how `{'2', '8', '0'}` came?

Comment: sorry Chester, can i just understand this: the sequence of the keys will be jumbled up when i run the function created right? Because the sequence of the output that i got is `{'2', '0', '8'}` but your commented line shows `{'0', '2', '8'}` . Or did you sort it so it's easier for me to see it in sequential order? :)

Comment: @jackie I returned a `set` which is an unordered collection data type. So, the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @jackie Glad to help ;) If it helped accept this as answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Ch3steR`s answer is very good. This one is practically the same but maybe a little easier to understand:

```
dict = {'0': ['a','c','d','e','b','f'],
             '1': ['c','b'],
             '2': ['a','d','e','b','g'],
             '3': ['a','c','d','b','g'],
             '4': ['g','c','f','b'],
             '5': ['a','c','d','g','f'],
             '6': ['a','c','d','e','g','f'],
             '7': ['a','c','b'],
             '8': ['a','c','d','e','b','g','f'],
             '9': ['a','c','d','b','g','f']}

def listfromstr(input1):
        c = []
        for i in input1:
                c.append(i)
        return c

def guesschar(dict1, str1):
        listofTruekeys = []
        listofstr = listfromstr(str1)
        for i in dict1:
                if all(elem in dict1[i] for elem in listofstr):
                        listofTruekeys.append(i)

        return listofTruekeys

print(guesschar(dict, 'abed'))
```

Output:

> ['0', '2', '8']

Comment: hi hackerer! I tried running your code and it works too!! Thank you for your help!!:)

Comment: Glad to help! :) If it helped than please upvote! I need that reputation. ;)